# Why am I only getting 130 volts at some power sockets?

Tags: electrical, wiring

In my living room (in Germany) I have one line, going from the fusebox around the walls with around 7 power sockets on it.

Four of those sockets have the normal 230V on them and work properly. Three however only have 120V on them. I've measured the voltage between the line and neutral. I've also measured between the ground and the 2 lines to see if there was a short-circuit but nothing showed.

I've tried checking all the lines in the walls to see if one of them is not properly connected, but from what I could see all lines, neutrals and grounds are properly connected.

The voltage at the fuse box is 230V, so the the fusebox itself is fine.

Does anyone have an idea why on the same circuit 4 boxes have 240V and 3 boxes have only 120V?

Comment: Can we presume you're in a 240V country?

Comment: actually...it's 230V standard, let me update that.

Comment: Did you mean neuters, or neutrals?  ;-)

Comment: What country is this?  What type of electrical service feeds the premises? e.g. UK single phase 230v 50hz    or US split phase 120/240v 60hz

Comment: Maybe an American used to live there and he messed with the wiring so he could plug in his Nintendo and his Sony.

Comment: not funny guys :P   The voltage on a single phase is 230V 50Hz, so UK system.

Comment: What tool did you use to measure the voltages?

Comment: multimeter. Wanted to use fingers first but GF found it not safe.

Answer (score 2):

> **Does anyone have an idea why on the same circuit 4 boxes have 240V and 3 boxes have only 120V?**

It may be there is a loose/corroded/burned connection in the 4th or 5th circuit box.

It may be you are using a voltage detector that has LED indicators for specific voltages, and does not make an exact measurement.

[image]

I would turn off the circuit breaker for that circuit, lock it out (to prevent other people turning it on), verify that nothing is live, verify again, then check resistance from live on 4th socket to live on 5th socket using a good quality Cat-II or better meter.

[image]

Comment: will definitely give this a spin and see what comes out of it.